# HELP! WI-FI is not working at all for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking

I have just switched to Ubuntu Linux 17.10. I am having trouble connecting my wireless Internet. I don't know where's and what's the problem. I am attaching an image to figure it out.

[image]

I'm new to Linux so help me accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the terminal command:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

I suspect that the response will be:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

This is the subject of a recent and still open bug in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1572659

It appears that the only solution so far is to enter the computer's BIOS and turn off Secure Boot.

Secure Boot is a security standard developed by the PC industry to help make sure that your PC boots using only software that is trusted by the PC manufacturer

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after disabling secure boot.  Have a good day. :)